# add autoplay in this piece of code?

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('a.link').click(function () {  


        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 200);
        setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud1', '0px', '5px', '20px', '30px')
        setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud2', '0px', '100px', '200px', '400px')
        setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud3', '0px', '15px', '30x', '45px')
        $('a.link').removeClass('selected');  
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;  
    });
```

Comment: to add autoplay plugin for my website slideshow

Comment: That is no question, its not even a complete sentence. Why don't you add a proper description and a precise question? Otherwise your question will get downvoted and closed soon, because nobody wants to answer something vague and nobody here can read minds.

Comment: is there a way to upload my files, so you'll have something specific to see. (I just want to make my scrolling to auto play), that is s all

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

1. isolate the behavior into a function,
2. call the function on document ready,
3. assign the function to the a.link click event.

**Code**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    myFunc();

    $('a.link').click( myFunc );

 }

 function myFunc() {

     $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 200);
     setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud1', '0px', '5px', '20px', '30px')
     setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud2', '0px', '100px', '200px', '400px')
     setPosition($(this).attr('href'), '#cloud3', '0px', '15px', '30x', '45px')
     $('a.link').removeClass('selected');  
     $(this).addClass('selected');
     return false; 

 }
```

Comment: thank you Steven, I'll try out, but i have another question, due to my lack of experience because I am a graphic designer and I am trying to make my website, could you please add me the piece of code inside the lines, instead I will jumble up, whole night!